# Portfolio web site with adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, html

I do a lot of interface design in Adobe Illustrator. I'd like to use my designs to create a portfolio web site.

Is there a simple way to build a website directly with the Illustrator files?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to GDSE. I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Do you want to know how to make a portfolio website that shows your work? Or make a website where people can use your designs for their own portfolios?

Comment: Using adobe Behance?

Comment: Yes i want to make a portfolio website that show me work from AI to an online version where i don't need to cut it and resize it for hours.

Comment: béhance yes but that's not what i want to share with clients and i can't integrate it i think

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator is merely an **image editor**. Nothing more.

While more recent versions of AI have seen things like CSS and SVG more integrated, these are woefully lacking in terms of actually creating a web page.

Illustrator is not designed to build even a single web page, let alone an entire web site.

One would, at the very least, need a good text editor and an understanding of HTML/CSS, or a What-You_see-Is-What-You-Get (WYSIWYG) HTML editor, such as Dreamweaver to build a web page. And then utilize *exported* images from Illustrator. You can't build a "web page" with Illustrator.

Comment: Make sens. So no direct way, I'll need to cut it in part and use some website builder. Thx for your feedback

Comment: Unfortunately "Cut and resize for hours" is standard. It's the same as for any project. I sure wish there was a quick and easy way :)

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator is used primarily to create components and layouts for web.  You can still use AI to get the visuals right, but as far as building a portfolio website you will need to use different software.  Depending on the software used, CSS styles from AI might be useful, images exported from AI will certainly be useful once you optimize them for web. There is so much more to web besides layouts - responsive behavior, accessibility, analytics, etc. - that AI would not be able to support it without becoming a completely different software. I would recommend approaching it from a different angle - first find a cheap or free web builder service you want to use for your portfolio website, and work within that services' templates to create your portfolio.

Comment: thx for the advice